# Selecting data based on the distance from a query point in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a data-set that has four columns [X Y Z C]. I would like to find all the C values that are in a given sphere centered at [X, Y, Z] with a radius r. What is the best approach to address this problem? Should I use the clusterdata command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses naively euclidean distance:

say `V = [X Y Z C]` is your dataset,  `Center = [x,y,z]` is the center of the sphere, then

```
dist = bsxfun(@minus,V(:,1:3),Center);  % // finds the distance vectors 
                                        % // between the points and the center
dist = sum(dist.^2,2); % // evaluate the squares of the euclidean distances (scalars)
idx = (dist < r^2);    % // Find the indexes of the matching points
```

The good `C` values are

```
 good = V(idx,4);  % // here I kept just the C column
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not "cluster analysis": You do not attempt to **discover structure** in your data.

Instead, what you are doing, is commonly called a "range query" or "radius query". In classic database terms, a `SELECT`, with a distance selector.

You probably want to define your sphere using euclidean distance. For computational purposes, it actually is beneficial to instead of *squared* Euclidean, by simply taking the square of your radius.

I don't use matlab, but there must be tons of examples of how to compute the distance of each instance in a data set from a query point, and then selecting those objects where the distance is small enough.

I don't know if there is any good *index structures* package for Matlab. But in general, at 3D, this can be well accelerated with index structures. Computing all distances is `O(n)`, but with an index structure only `O(log n)`.